# How to quickly fill a list with a range of numbers

Tags: optimization, ti-basic

I have a program where I have a list from 0:90 and a second list that is calculated at each point using this list. the equation cant be written as a function that can be easily plotted so i use a stat plot to plot on list as x and the other as y

I want to define the 0-90 list each time but i cant find a way to define the whole list in one foul swoop like in another language

(Im thinking of MATLAB where I could easily go L1=0:.1:90)

Instead I use a for loop to define each value one at a time, although this is quite slow.

Is there a way define the list in a matlab style way like above? If not is there some way I could speed this up? I also calculate each value of the other list indivudually during the for loop so if i could quickly define the first then i think I could quickly calculate the second without the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this for both lists. To initialize the first list you can do something like this:

```
seq(I,I,0,90→L1
```

This will store the list `{0 1 2 ... 89 90}` into `L1`. Then, you can do whatever calculation you like. For example, to initialize the first list like you want and do a calculation like X<sup>2</sup>+1 to get your second list, you could do:

```
seq(I,I,0,90→L1
L1²+1→L2
```

This would store the new list `{1 2 5 ... 7922 8101}` into `L2`. Finally, you can combine them if you want:

```
seq(I²+1,I,0,90
```

This would generate the same list `{1 2 5 ... 7922 8101}` as before. Let me know if you have any further questions and I'll be glad to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its definitely more convienent to type although it isnt that much faster. I guess i expected too much from my calculator